# How to inject java.io.File and then set its name

Tags: java, file, unit-testing, dependency-injection, mockito

I have an interesting scenario where I need to inject a `File` reference into my POJO (so that, in my test classes, I can stub the `File` and not actually write anything to disk), but the *name* of the file won't actually be known until runtime:

```
public class MyPOJO {
    private File file;

    private FileWriter writer;

    // Getter and setter for file & writer

    public void writeToDisk(String message) {
        String fileName = complexLogicToBuildFileName();

        // How do I do the equivalent of: file.setName(fileName);

        try {
            writer.write(message);

            writer.close();
        } catch(IOException ioe) {
            ...
        }
    }
}

public class MyPOJOTest {
    @Test
    public void verifyWriteToDiskAttemptsToWrite() {
        MyPOJO pojo = new MyPOJO();
        File mockFile = Mockito.mock(File.class);
        FileWriter mockWriter = Mockito.mock(FileWriter.class);

        Mockito.doNothing().when(mockWriter).write(Mockito.anyString());

        pojo.setWriter(mockWriter);
        pojo.setFile(mockFile);

        pojo.writeToDisk("This won't write to disk.");

        Mockito.verify(mockWriter).write("This won't write to disk.");
    }
}
```

The problem is, because of the forced `File(String)` constructor, I have to bind my injected `File` instance to a file name *before* I have a chance to execute `complexLogicToBuildFileName()`, and this can't be overwritten with a simple setter method. Any ideas as to how I could preserve `file` and `fileWriter` as being injected properties (for testability's sake), but still let me use `complexLogicToBuildFileName()` to name the file? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't understand why you're injecting a `File` *and* a `FileWriter`, and your POJO derives a filename too (via `complexLogicToBuildFileName()`).

If you want to abstract out the writing, why not simply inject your POJO with a `Writer` (interface) and you can choose a mocked version (or even a `StringWriter`) rather than provide a `FileWriter`. You can then extract the `complexLogicToBuildFileName()` into a new object (say, `FileNameBuilder`) and test that separately.